# Lua table.toString(tableName) and table.fromString(stringTable) functions?

Tags: serialization, lua, lua-table

I am wanting to convert a 2d lua table into a string, then after converting it to a string convert it back into a table using that newly created string. It seems as if this process is called serialization, and is discussed in the below url, yet I am having a difficult time understanding the code and was hoping someone here had a simple table.toString and table.fromString function
http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code lhf posted is a much simpler code example than anything from the page you linked, so hopefully you can understand it better. Adapting it to output a string instead of printing the output looks like:

```
t = {
{11,12,13},
{21,22,23},
}

local s = {"return {"}
for i=1,#t do
  s[#s+1] = "{"
  for j=1,#t[i] do
    s[#s+1] = t[i][j]
    s[#s+1] = ","
  end
  s[#s+1] = "},"
end
s[#s+1] = "}"
s = table.concat(s)

print(s)
```

The general idea with serialization is to take all the bits of data from some data structure like a table, and then loop through that data structure while building up a string that has all of those bits of data along with formatting characters.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I meant redefining `print` or using a different function to collect the output in a table so that you could keep my original code mostly intact.

Comment: I hate overloading functions because I always forget that I changed it.

Comment: I believe `#t` has to do some iterating to calculate the length of a table. It may be more efficient to use your own length-counter variable.

Comment: isn't this answer is only valid for arrays? Assuming your index starts on 1 and follows the sequence... What about general-purpose tables (indexed by whatever values, like strings... aka, Hashtables)?

Comment: I would strongly suggest JSON for this purpose (ie. dosimple's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6078812/686008 ). My answer more addresses the approach linked in the question, but really a better approach is serializing to JSON.

Comment: this language is maddness.

Answer (score 25):

I am using the following code in order to serialize tables:

```
function serializeTable(val, name, skipnewlines, depth)
    skipnewlines = skipnewlines or false
    depth = depth or 0

    local tmp = string.rep(" ", depth)

    if name then tmp = tmp .. name .. " = " end

    if type(val) == "table" then
        tmp = tmp .. "{" .. (not skipnewlines and "\n" or "")

        for k, v in pairs(val) do
            tmp =  tmp .. serializeTable(v, k, skipnewlines, depth + 1) .. "," .. (not skipnewlines and "\n" or "")
        end

        tmp = tmp .. string.rep(" ", depth) .. "}"
    elseif type(val) == "number" then
        tmp = tmp .. tostring(val)
    elseif type(val) == "string" then
        tmp = tmp .. string.format("%q", val)
    elseif type(val) == "boolean" then
        tmp = tmp .. (val and "true" or "false")
    else
        tmp = tmp .. "\"[inserializeable datatype:" .. type(val) .. "]\""
    end

    return tmp
end
```

the code created can then be executed using loadstring(): http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring if you have passed an argument to 'name' parameter (or append it afterwards):

```
s = serializeTable({a = "foo", b = {c = 123, d = "foo"}})
print(s)
a = loadstring(s)()
```

Comment: you know, tostring works on booleans too. tostring(true) == "true"

Comment: This code does not handle things like `a={}; a[1]=2;` however. (`{1=2}` is not dostring-able) Also for nil etc.. For pretty printing there are already other libraries however.

Comment: For numeric keys like `{1=...}` I added this line: `if type(k) == "number" then k = "[\"" .. tostring(k) .. "\"]" end` in the for loop.

Answer (score 10):

How about a [JSON module](http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules)? That way you have also a better exchangeable data. I usually prefer dkjson, which also supports utf-8, where cmjjson won't.

Comment: Upvote for making me realize that JSON was the better solution. I already *had* a JSON library that I was using in the project, even, but I'd forgotten.

Answer (score 6):

Under the kong works this

```
local cjson = require "cjson"
kong.log.debug(cjson.encode(some_table))
```

Out of the kong should be installed package lua-cjson https://github.com/openresty/lua-cjson/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple program which assumes your table contains numbers only. It outputs Lua code that can be loaded back with `loadstring()()`. Adapt it to output to a string instead of printing it out. Hint: redefine print to collect the output into a table and then at the end turn the output table into a string with `table.concat`.

```
t = {
{11,12,13},
{21,22,23},
}

print"return {"
for i=1,#t do
        print"{"
        for j=1,#t[i] do
                print(t[i][j],",")
        end
        print"},"
end
print"}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that:

- You don't have loops (table a referencing table b and b referencing a)
- Your tables are pure arrays (all keys are consecutive positive integers, starting on 1)
- Your values are integers only (no strings, etc)

Then a recursive solution is easy to implement:

```
function serialize(t)
  local serializedValues = {}
  local value, serializedValue
  for i=1,#t do
    value = t[i]
    serializedValue = type(value)=='table' and serialize(value) or value
    table.insert(serializedValues, serializedValue)
  end
  return string.format("{ %s }", table.concat(serializedValues, ', ') )
end
```

Prepend the string resulting from this  function with a `return`, store it on a .lua file:

```
-- myfile.lua
return { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }
```

You can just use [dofile](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-dofile) to get the table back.

```
t = dofile 'myfile.lua'
```

Notes:

- If you have loops, then you will have
  to handle them explicitly - usually with an extra table to "keep track" of repetitions
- If you don't have pure arrays, then
  you will have to parse t differently,
  as well as handle the way the keys are rendered (are they strings? are they other tables? etc).
- If you have more than just integers
  and subtables, then calculating
  `serializedValue` will be more
  complex.

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I have shorter code to convert table to string but not reverse

```
function compileTable(table)
   local index = 1
   local holder = "{"
   while true do
      if type(table[index]) == "function" then
         index = index + 1
      elseif type(table[index]) == "table" then
         holder = holder..compileTable(table[index])
      elseif type(table[index]) == "number" then
         holder = holder..tostring(table[index])
      elseif type(table[index]) == "string" then
         holder = holder.."\""..table[index].."\""
      elseif table[index] == nil then
         holder = holder.."nil"
      elseif type(table[index]) == "boolean" then
         holder = holder..(table[index] and "true" or "false")
      end
      if index + 1 > #table then
        break
      end
      holder = holder..","
      index = index + 1
   end
   return holder.."}"
end
```

if you want change the name just search all compileTable change it to you preferred name because this function will call it self if it detect nested table but escape sequence I don't know if it work

if you use this to create a lua executable file that output the table it will ge compilation error if you put new line and " sequence
this method is more memory efficient

Note:

1. Function not supported
2. User data I don't know

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
local nl = string.char(10) -- newline
function serialize_list (tabl, indent)
    indent = indent and (indent.."  ") or ""
    local str = ''
    str = str .. indent.."{"
    for key, value in pairs (tabl) do
        local pr = (type(key)=="string") and ('["'..key..'"]=') or ""
        if type (value) == "table" then
            str = str..nl..pr..serialize_list (value, indent)..','
        elseif type (value) == "string" then
            str = str..nl..indent..pr..'"'..tostring(value)..'",'
        else
            str = str..nl..indent..pr..tostring(value)..','
        end
    end
    str = str:sub(1, #str-1) -- remove last symbol
    str = str..nl..indent.."}"
    return str
end

local str = serialize_list(tables)
print('return '..nl..str)
```